# Finding a substring in files across subdirectories with a single built-in command?

Tags: linux, grep, find, recursive

In Windows, if I wanted to find a string across all files in all subdirectories, I would do something like

```
findstr /C:"the string" /S *.h
```

However, in Linux (say, Ubuntu) I have found no other way than some piped command involving `find`, `xargs`, and `grep` (an example is at this page: [How can I recursively grep through sub-directories?](http://aplawrence.com/Unixart/recursivegrep.html)). However, my question is different: is there any *single, built-in command* that works through this magic, without having to write my shell script?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

GNU grep allows searching recursively through subdirectories:

```
grep -r --include='*.h' 'the string' .
```

Comment: I tried this exact command line in Ubuntu but get "grep: invalid option -- 'M'" although I can't see any 'M' anywhere... puzzling

Comment: @Guido Works fine over here

Comment: In a [suggested edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/edit-suggestions/25) [TomasG](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4695/tomasg) recommends changing the last `*` to `'*'`: "Quoting the last wildcard is needed to avoid errors when some filename starts with -"

Comment: In a strange twist of events, it now works for me too, as entered in the original answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Guido: Your problem may have been due to a file in the current directory called `-Msomething`, or to a [`GREP_OPTIONS`](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/24141/) setting.

Answer (score 2):

`grep -r searchpattern /path/to/start/in`

Where `/path/to/start/in/` can be just "`.`" for the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

No.  `find -name \*.h -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l 'the regex'` is as magic as it gets.

Comment: GNU grep has the common cases built-in with its `-r` option. No need for the heavy artillery.

Comment: `xargs` adds just noise. Use `find -name \*.h -execdir grep -l 'the regex {} +`

Answer (score 1):

To find string from given directory use below command

```
find <fullDirectoryPath> -name '*' -exec grep -l '<StringToFind>' {} \;
```

For example:

```
find /apps_bev/apps/xfer/export/02210 -name '*' -exec grep -l '38221000001032' {} \;
```

Comment: `grep` can take more than one file as arguments, so you should use `+` instead of `\;` to avoid running one `grep` invocation per file which is quite inefficient.

Comment: Note that `-name '*'` restricts to files whose name is valid text in the current locale (in some `find` implementations at least), but the other directory components may still contain sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters. If your intention with that `-name '*'` was to make sure the output is valid text (by omiting the files with improper names), you'd rather use `find ... ! -name '*' -prune -o -exec grep ... {} +`, which would also stop `find` from descending into directories with improper names.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any *single, built-in command* that works through this magic ... ?

To be pedantic, **no, you cannot assume such a command exists**.

There are many different implementations of Unix, and each has its different quirks. POSIX, the common denominator (and closest thing to a standard across Unices) [does not specify such an option for `grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html).

As mentionned in other answers, GNU's implementation of `grep` has a non-standard option that does what you want. While this particular implementation might be common on Linux systems, you cannot assume its availability on any Unix, even some Linux systems.

Finally, I should mention that it is the [Unix philosophy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy) to favor the combination of several primitive programs, over the use of one big monolithic executable attempting to do everything at once.

In your case, crawling the file system and matching regexp in a stream are two separate tasks. It is only normal to treat each in a separate program.