# How to search for file contents

Tags: grep, files, find, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding a substring in files across subdirectories with a single built-in command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7383/finding-a-substring-in-files-across-subdirectories-with-a-single-built-in-command)

I know that I can use grep for a single file, but what about a whole directory tree?