# Find a string only in a specific file inside subdirectories

Tags: grep, wildcards, recursive

Let's say I need to find the function `GetTypes()` in all C# source file (`.cs`) the directories/subdirectories.

I used `grep -rn GetTypes *.cs`, but I got an error with `grep: *.cs: No such file or directory`. I had to use `grep -rn GetTypes *`, but in this case it shows all the files not `*.cs` only.

What command do I need to use to find the string only in `.cs` files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding a substring in files across subdirectories with a single built-in command?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7383/finding-a-substring-in-files-across-subdirectories-with-a-single-built-in-comman)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your shell is bash ≥4, put `shopt -s globstar` in your `~/.bashrc`. If your shell is zsh, you're good. Then you can run

```
grep -n GetTypes **/*.cs
```

`**/*.cs` means all the files matching `*.cs` in the current directory, or in its subdirectories, recursively.

If you're not running a shell that supports `**` but your grep supports `--include`, you can do a recursive grep and tell `grep` to only consider files matching certain patterns. Note the quotes around the file name pattern: it's interpreted by grep, not by the shell.

```
grep -rn --include='*.cs' GetTypes .
```

With only portable tools (some systems don't have `grep -r` at all), use `find` for the directory traversal part, and `grep` for the text search part.

```
find . -name '*.cs' -exec grep -n GetTypes {} +
```

Comment: To temporary set the `globstar` option for a current Bash 4+ shell, use: `shopt -s globstar`.

Answer (score 8):

You should check out the billiant little grep/find replacement known as [`ack`](http://betterthangrep.com/). It is specifically setup for searching through directories of source code files.

Your command would look like this:

```
ack --csharp GetTypes
```

Answer (score 6):

If you use GNU `grep`, you can specify which files to include in a recursive directory traversal:

```
grep --include '*.cs' -rn GetTypes .
```

(where the last period denotes the current working directory as root of the traversal)

Answer (score 4):

I'm using a combination of find and grep:

```
find . -name "*.cs" | xargs grep "GetTypes" -bn --color=auto
```

For `find`, you can replace `.` by a directory and remove `-name` if you want to look in every file.

For `grep`, `-bn` will print the position and the line number and `--color` will help your eyes by highlighting what you are looking for.