# grep for log files in subdirectories when there are none in the current directory, but plenty in subs

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have to find some words in a lot of log files after I've run a failed build.

1. If I do that:

```
grep -r "myword"
```

I have too much responses. I don't want to search all the files in all the sub directories.

2. If I do that:

```
grep -r "myword" *.xml
```

It works because I have an *.xml file in current directory, but I have no responses because... it's not that kind of file I'm searching for.

3. If I do that:

```
grep -r "myword" *.log
```

It responds:
*No file or directory of that type*

because there's no log file in the current directory.
But there are plenty of them, below, in `target` subdirectories. (a `find . -name *.log` will list me them).

How shall I write the grep command to achieve the result I want?
I've tried to end my command with a variety of `*.log`, `.log`, `**/*.log`, `*/**/*.log`, but without success.

Comment: Relating: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14498/315749

Comment: @fra-san I had no success with `grep -rn "myword" **/*.log` or `grep -n "myword" *.log` suggested in this post.

Comment: The `find` alternative in the linked Q/A is the portable one (i.e. works in any POSIX shell). Those based on `**` depend on the shell you are using. E.g. if it's Bash, check your version and make sure `shopt globstar` says "on" (turn it on with `shopt -s globstar`); with zsh it should work by default. If your question cannot be considered a duplicate of the Q/A I linked to, please add the shell you are using to it.

Comment: @fcbsd I'm unable to remind a so long command.

Comment: This won't help you immediately, but the trick is not to remember this long command. The trick is to get familiar with `find`, so you can craft such command *anew* whenever you need and tailor it to your requirements. BTW the exact command posted by @fcbsd cannot work, it uses `()` where `{}` should be.

Comment: With GNU grep, you should be able to use `grep -r --include='*.log' myword`

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, this one works. Thanks!

Comment: fixed verison:  `find . -name "*.log" -type f -exec grep "myword" {} \; -print` when I need to use grep in multiple directories – fcbsd 2 hours ago   Delete