# How can I use grep to search multiple unnested directories?

Tags: grep, search

It may sound like I'm asking the same thing as [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7383/22172), but I have different requirements. This is an example of my filesystem:

- /code/

  - internal/

    - dev/
    - main/
  - public/

    - dev/
    - main/
    - release/
  - tools/

`/code/internal/dev/`, `/code/public/dev/` and `/code/tools/` contain subdirectories for multiple projects. I work almost exclusively in the dev branches of `/code/internal/` and `/code/public/`, and often I want to search for a text string in those directories along with `/code/tools/` (which has no branches). In these instances I have to do three separate commands:

```
$ grep -r "some string" /code/internal/dev/
$ grep -r "some string" /code/public/dev/
$ grep -r "some string" /code/tools/
```

I'd like to know if there's a single command to do this. If not, I would most likely need to write a simple bash script.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can concatenate several paths for grep to look for:

```
grep -r "some string" /code/internal/dev/ /code/public/dev/ /code/tools/
```

Comment: This is so obvious. Why didn't I think of this?!

Answer (score 22):

If you want to make maximal use of wildcards (and the hierarchy you posted is complete), you can do

```
grep -r "some string" /code/{*/dev,tools}/*.cs
```

## Explanation:

The first step done is expansion of the braced list. `foo{bar,baz}qux` expands to `foobarqux foobazqux`. That is, there's a separate word generated for each comma-separated item in the list, with the prefix and postfix part attached to each. You can see how that works by doing

```
echo A{1,2,3,4}B
```

which outputs

```
A1B A2B A3B A4B
```

Note that this also works with multiple braces, and also with empty arguments; for example

```
echo {,1,2}{0,1,2}:{2,3}
```

gives

```
0:2 0:3 1:2 1:3 2:2 2:3 10:2 10:3 11:2 11:3 12:2 12:3 20:2 20:3 21:2 21:3 22:2 22:3
```

So after brace expansion, your command looks like this:

```
grep -r "some string" /code/*/dev/*.cs /code/tools/*.cs
```

The next step is wildcard expansion. You already know that for the `*.cs` part, but it also works for intermediate directories; moreover, if a `/` follows, only directories are matched. Therefore given your hierarchy (and making up file names for the `.cs` files), you'll get the command:

```
grep -r "some string" /code/internal/dev/file1.cs /code/internal/dev/file2.cs /code/public/dev/file3.cs /code/tools/file4.cs /code/tools/file5.cs
```

Only after all this has happened, `grep` is called with this list of arguments (note that the same happens with your original commands; `grep` never gets to see the `*`; expanding that is completely done by `bash` before calling `grep`).